Connecting to PowerBI XMLA endpoint using ADOMD - Getting Invalid Token Type error
I have an XMLA endpoint which I can connect to using both SSMS and Dax Studio, but cannot seem to connect to using ADOMD in C#.
Here is the C# code I am trying out:
using Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient;

class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Configuration
        string xmlaEndpoint = "powerbi://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/<my org>";
        string scope = "https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api/.default";

        try
        {
            // Step 1: Acquire an access token using DefaultAzureCredential
            Console.WriteLine("Acquiring access token using Azure Default Credential...");
            var credential = new InteractiveBrowserCredential();
            var tokenRequestContext = new Azure.Core.TokenRequestContext(new[] { scope });
            var accessToken = (await credential.GetTokenAsync(tokenRequestContext)).Token;
            Console.WriteLine("Access token acquired successfully.");

            // Step 2: Create connection string using the access token
            string connectionString = $"Data Source={xmlaEndpoint};Authentication=Bearer;Password={accessToken};";

            // Step 3: Connect to the XMLA endpoint and execute a query
            using (AdomdConnection connection = new AdomdConnection(connectionString))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Opening connection...");
                connection.Open();

                string query = "EVALUATE TOPN( 500, Invoices )";
                using (AdomdCommand command = new AdomdCommand(query, connection))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Executing query...");
                    using (AdomdDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(reader["Name"]);
                        }
                    }
                }

                connection.Close();
                Console.WriteLine("Connection closed successfully.");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Error: {ex.Message}");
        }
    }
}

I get the following exception:
Error: MWC token validation failed: Invalid Token type, expected ServiceToken but got AadBasedToken
I am using the exact same credentials as when I connect using DAX Studio or SSMS.
Also, the access token generated by the code above can be used successfully to interact with the PowerBI REST API.
So I am not sure what DAX Studio and SSMS are doing differently.

Have you tried authenticating using Client Credential Flow (Service Principal) rather than using InteractiveBrowserCredential.


MWC token validation failed: Invalid Token type, expected ServiceToken but got AadBasedToken

Above error indicates that Power BI XMLA endpoints expect a Service Principal Token (ServiceToken) rather than a regular Azure AD user token (AadBasedToken).

DAX Studio and SSMS automatically handle interactive login flows or use delegated user tokens in a way that the XMLA endpoint accepts.

However, ADOMD.NET in C# requires a Service Principal or a token that clearly identifies as a ServiceToken.


Firstly, Register an Azure Entra App (Service Principal) and assign Power BI Admin and Analysis Services Admin roles. Grant Tenant.ReadWrite.All and App.ReadWrite.All API permissions (delegated).
Modified Code:
using Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient;
using Azure.Identity;
using Azure.Core;
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Configuration
        string xmlaEndpoint = "powerbi://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/<workspace-name>";
        string tenantId = "<your-tenant-id>";
        string clientId = "<your-client-id>";
        string clientSecret = "<your-client-secret>";
        string scope = "https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api/.default";

        try
        {
            // Step 1: Acquire access token using ClientSecretCredential (Service Principal)
            Console.WriteLine("Acquiring access token with ClientSecretCredential...");

            var credential = new ClientSecretCredential(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret);
            var tokenRequestContext = new TokenRequestContext(new[] { scope });
            var accessToken = (await credential.GetTokenAsync(tokenRequestContext)).Token;

            Console.WriteLine("Access token acquired successfully.");
            
            // Step 2: Create connection string (without token in connection string)
            string connectionString = $"Data Source={xmlaEndpoint};";

            // Step 3: Open ADOMD connection
            using (AdomdConnection connection = new AdomdConnection(connectionString))
            {
                // Apply the access token manually using SessionID
                connection.SessionID = accessToken;

                Console.WriteLine("Opening connection to XMLA endpoint...");
                connection.Open();

                // Step 4: Execute DAX Query
                string query = "EVALUATE TOPN(500, Invoices)";

                using (AdomdCommand command = new AdomdCommand(query, connection))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Executing query...");
                    using (AdomdDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(reader[0]);  // Print first column (adjust as needed)
                        }
                    }
                }

                connection.Close();
                Console.WriteLine("Connection closed successfully.");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Error: {ex.Message}");
        }
    }
}

Result:


This works, but do you know how I can do it without a service principal?
